# Comparison of vacua and annihilation operators of Klein-Gordon theory and phi-fourth theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, interactions, klein-gordon-equation

The ground state or vacuum of an interacting theory is, in general, different from the ground state or vacuum of a free theory. In what cases are the two vacuums the same as each other?

Can an interacting vacuum be written in terms of a free vacuum? For concreteness, let's use the (free) Klein-Gordon theory and the (interacting) phi-fourth theory.

---

The action of the annihilation operator $a_{p}$ on the free Klein-Gordon vacuum $|0\rangle$ gives 0. The action of the annihilation operator $a_{p}$ on the interacting phi-fourth vacuum $|\Omega\rangle$ also gives 0.

Are the annihilation operators the same in both cases? Or are the annihilation operators different for the two theories?

Comment: This sort of a topic is very open to interpretation, although there is a straightforward perturbative answer that you are most likely familiar with. It would help to hear your own perspective.